# Pro Player is slowing my website

Tags: wordpress

i have a wordpress blog/website and since a few months ago i'm using the PRO PLAYER plugin to embed vídeos.
It happens that with the increase of the number of vídeos embeded, now, mainly the first page of my website is loading very slowly. I checked all the plugins to see which one was turning my site so slow and found it was pro player ( http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/proplayer/ ).

So i'm here to ask, there is some solution to mantain pro player and turn my website faster?
If not, i guess i have to change the video player of my website. Anyone can recommend me a light video player to use? a good one for wordpress?

Thank you!

Comment: You should be asking the author of ProPlayer this question. However, if this video is hosted elsewhere (like YouTube), view the video on Youtube, to see if the issue resides in the plugin or something else.

Comment: Now that you mention it, i guess the plugin doesn't have an update since a long time, maybe it droped the development :/

Answer (score 0):

Here are the few points that you may opt to enhance your website speed -

1. `Uninstall` the unnecessary plugins.
2. If you are able to write code then `avoid using heavy plugins`, like
   twitter, FB etc(try using available widgets from the main site).
3. If you are using very much images and video streaming on your site,
   try using `Cache plugins`.
4. `Limit the number of posts` on front page as this may also cause some
   trouble. Use light weighted theme.

Comment: I guess i will look for cache plugins or for another player video. The other points you mentioned, some are already done, others are out of option like point 4.
Thanks for the reply.